# GLSL function parameters

Tags: glsl

In [GLSL: Common Mistakes](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/GLSL_:_common_mistakes#Functions_inputs_and_outputs) it states:

> Functions parameters must be declared with the `in`, `out`, or `inout` qualifiers.

but I have never declared function parameters with `in`, `out`, or `inout` qualifiers and I have never run into any problems. Could this be because of my specific graphics card? What are the side effects of not using the `in`, `out`, or `inout` qualifiers?

Info: I am using GLSL 3.3 and I have an Intel graphics card

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The GLSL Specification](https://khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf) in section 6.1.1 "Function Calling Conventions" states:

> - The keyword **in** is used as a qualifier to denote a parameter is to be copied in, but not copied out.
> - The keyword **out** is used as a qualifier to denote a parameter is to be copied out, but not copied in. This should be used whenever possible to avoid unnecessarily copying parameters in.
> - The keyword **inout** is used as a qualifier to denote the parameter is to be both copied in and copied out. It means the same thing as specifying both in and out.
> - A function parameter declared with no such qualifier means the same thing as specifying **in**.

Comment: It should be noted that this is true for all versions of GLSL, all the way back to 1.10 and even the ES versions.